# Entity framework Core with Identity and ASP.NET Core RC2 not creating user in database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an application with authentication.  I am using the following frameworks:

- ASP.NET Core RC2
- Entity Framework Core
- The Npgsql EFCore driver

For seeding I created a `DataSeeder` class, that gets added as Transient Service in the `ConfigureServices` function and later called in the Configure function. It checks whether an `IdentityUser` exists, and if not it creates one called admin and adds the role Admin to it.

However, when adding the role to the user, I get an exception saying that a foreign key constraint gets violated and that the ASP_NET_USERS does not contain an entry with that PK.

I checked the database and it does indeed contain the new Role that I created, but the user table is still empty.

Here is my `DataSeeder` class:

```cs
public class DataSeeder {
    private DatabaseContext _context;
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public DataSeeder(DatabaseContext ctx, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) {
        _context = ctx;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task CreateUserAsync() {
        if (! await _userManager.Users.AnyAsync()) {
            var adminRole = new IdentityRole("admin");
            var rootRole = new IdentityRole("root");

            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole);
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(rootRole);

            var user = new IdentityUser {
                Email = "blabla@example.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                UserName = "superadmin"
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@SSWORD");

            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("role", "admin"));
        }
    }
}
```

So the exception is thrown at `AddClaimAsync`. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I can't look right now, but IIRC createAsync returns a result object and you can see why it's not being created. I imagine it's because of password complexity or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the result of `_userManager.createAsync`.

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@SSWORD");

if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    // something went wrong, inspect the errors
}
```

You'll most likely find a required property on your `IdentityUser` is missing or the password is not valid.

Comment: Oke, that was a silly mistake.... I wouldve expected it to throw an Exception if any input was wrong, but it was just the password not having the required complexity -_-